# XmlHttpRequest cross-domain

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, put

Im trying to make requests to a remote Rest (put method) api

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("PUT", "http://api-easybib.apigee.com/2.0/rest/cite", true);
xhReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var jsonString = "{...}";

xhReq.send(JSON.stringify(jsonString));

var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
```

it fails with

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

**although i succeeded to make call via rest client browser plugins**.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because cause security, all browser are not accept a ajax cross-origin request from your site.

In order to browser accept a ajax cross-origin request, server code must set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to response to notify browser that it accept a ajax cross-origin request.

In a browser plugin (ex: chrome app), chrome allow developer config to send request cross-origin. So you can send cross-domain request in REST Client plugin. (http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#manifest)

Answer (score 0):

Add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your server or use JSONP
(see [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about))

Comment: do you mean to the Rest server?

Comment: Yes on the REST server you can add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: ITs not my server. its a Rest service and i know it support cross-domain as i mentioned

Comment: If it supported client side JS cross domain requests then you wouldn't get an error about it not including the header that grants permission to client side JavaScript.